# Web-service exception

Tags: java, xml, character-encoding, xml-serialization, jax-ws

We have a web-service that functions always properly but today we got 500-th error (server-side error) when reqeust was made from third-party side client. The exception thrown by this request is:

```
Jul 14, 2015 5:00:39 AM org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doDefaultLogging
WARNING: Interceptor for {http://tempuri.org/soaprequest}SoaprequestImplService has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Problems creating SAAJ object model
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJInInterceptor.handleMessage(SAAJInInterceptor.java:235)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJInInterceptor.handleMessage(SAAJInInterceptor.java:75)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:240)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.CxfWsContainer.onMessage(CxfWsContainer.java:86)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.webservices.WsServlet.service(WsServlet.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1157)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:627)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:809)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character (CTRL-CHAR, code 159); expected a semi-colon after the reference for entity 'Р'
 at javax.xml.stream.SerializableLocation@b4884c8b
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedChar(StreamScanner.java:639)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.parseEntityName(StreamScanner.java:2058)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.resolveNonCharEntity(StreamScanner.java:1479)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2786)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1071)
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.readDocElements(StaxUtils.java:1311)
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.readDocElements(StaxUtils.java:1194)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJInInterceptor.handleMessage(SAAJInInterceptor.java:223)
    ... 27 more
```

As I understand the request xml was not processed properly by Java XML API that has been used to serialize the request because it was malformed somewhere.
So to fix this error I want to imitate such a malformed request from my own client, but don't know how break request data so that I could get the same error. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did the data coming from third party client is URL-encoded? If not, recomment your third party client to provide data as url-encoded so that it may work.

Comment: @user1354678 Thank you for feedback. We cannot ask third-party to alter anyting, so we should fix it ourself. Could you please comment why URL-encoding can help in this? I've never used URL-encoding before and I can't see how I can apply this to my problem.

Comment: I am saying that, some special characters may not be received properly if the data is not properly url encoded. By default, every request is url encoded if made in a proper way. Different way of making requests will disable default url encoding feature

Comment: @user1354678 Could you give an example of such special character? may then I'll can try reproduce the same error.